# Django - template - check if a field has attribute

Tags: django, django-templates

**forms.py**

```
class someForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = someModel
        field = '__all__'
        widgets = {'length': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'has-checkbox'})}
```

I gave a form field an attribute like the above. The goal is to add an HTML code row that has checkbox. Something like this:

```
{% if field hasAttr('has-checkbox') %}
    <input type="checkbox">
    {{ field }}
{% end if %}
```

The problem is that I do not know Django Template version of code that does what `hasAttr()` does. This is a random function that I just made up to ask question here. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the widget with `field.field.widget` so something like this should work:

```
{% if 'has-checkbox' in field.field.widget.attrs.class %}
    <input type="checkbox">
    {{ field }}
{% endif %}
```